# How to correctly resize raster GIS images to a given px width?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I work on ETOPO1, a 466MB file, and want to move to SRTM (~20GB Earth). My workflow involve several time-consuming processing steps so I strongly want to work on a minimum raster. It usually want to take 10.000 to 100.000px width GIS rasters to scale them down to ~1000px width, like my final map.

**How to correctly resize a raster GIS file to a given width via terminal ?** (gdal prefered)

It should keep negative and positive z-values with precision.

---

**Note:** I already tried the following...

- **Crop:** to crop my area of insterest using `gdal_translate -projwin $(WEST) $(NORTH) $(EAST) $(SOUTH) ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop.tmp.tif`, it still give me files 50 times too big for a processing 50 times slower.
- **Early resizing:** early resizing with Imagemagick + reinjecting the GIS metadata for following processings destroys the negative values (altitudes under sea level become 0m).

Comment: Use gdal_translate with -outsize http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html or gdalwarp with -tr http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html. To keep z-values, result will naturally be resampled. Perhaps the default nearest neighbor sampling gives what you want.

Comment: Note: I will first crop, then resize. I know the width I want, but I don't know the height.

Comment: Then use gdalwarp with target extents (-te) and target resolution (-tr).

Comment: @user30184: I've been reading these commands definition for the pas 20mins without getting it. ***-te xmin ymin xmax ymax:** set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS).
**-tr xres yres:** set output file resolution (in target georeferenced units). **-ts width height:**
set output file size in pixels and lines. If width or height is set to 0, the other dimension will be guessed from the computed resolution. Note that -ts cannot be used with -tr.*

Comment: Write here the target BBOX you want to get and pixel size you aim at and I will write you the gdalwarp command to use. Resolution you can calculate from (target image width in meters)/(image width you want to have in pixels).

Comment: From my understanding, ***-te** set a decimal degrees bounding box; **-tr** xres yres: set output file resolution (in target georeferenced units)* which is thus not pixels. ***-ts width height*** is very blur since is says that if one dimension is 0, **the other dimension** is calculated, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, a live example with WEST=-5.0 NORTH=51.0 EAST=10 SOUTH=41, output width 1000px, output height unknow, will help me to get it. @user30184

Comment: I suppose that both input and output are in EPSG:4326. Try `gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326 -te -5 41 10 51 -tr 0.015 0.015 input.tif output.tif` There are some parameters which in your case are not necessary but it does not harm to be explicit. Also "If width or height is set to 0, the other dimension will be guessed from the computed resolution" would suit you perfectly. Leave -tr out and use -ts 1000 0. This way you can tell to creat 1000 pixel wide output and height automatically computed to suit.

Comment: Yes, both in epsg:4326. It indeed appears you have knowledges I don't. If I get it right, the man's **-ts** entry sentense should not be *"If width or height is set to 0, the other dimension will be guessed from the computed resolution"*, but *"If width or height is set to 0, THIS dimension will be guessed from the computed resolution"*.

Comment: @user30184: It's working, resized and keep negative values. the zrange is to update (`--mm`) but should be ok. Thanks a lot. You may create an answer "use ts 1000 0" that I will then validate and develop myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an area such as WEST=-5.0 NORTH=51.0 EAST=10 SOUTH=41, wanted width 1000px, height unknown, use:

```
gdalwarp -te -5 41 10 51 -ts 1000 0 input.tif output.tif
```

or :

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326 -te -5 41 10 51 -ts 1000 0 input.tif output.tif
```

Instead of gdal_translate, crop the image with [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) **-ts** option :

> **-ts width height:** set output file size in pixels and lines. If
>   width or height is set to 0, this dimension will be guessed from
>   the computed resolution. Note that -ts cannot be used with -tr.
>
> **-te xmin ymin xmax ymax:** set georeferenced extents of output file
>   to be created (in target SRS [usually decimal degrees]).

With `-ts 1000 0`you can set the width of the output to desired 1000 pixels and gdalwarp will compute the height automatically.

Comment: add -co TILED=YES and -co COMPRESS=LZW for more efficient access and storage, if your target usage can utilize those options